# JTextField in JDialog box is not getting focused

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, jdialog

I am making a save Dialog box using Swing GUI builder. I have used a `JDialog` box for this. I have some buttons and a `JTextField` (for the filename) in the dialog box.

The problem is that when I run the program, the text field is not getting focused when clicked and hence I cannot write into it. I even tried using `requestFocus()` but it doesn't help. I do not understand why this is happening and how to resolve this.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    jTextField1.requestFocus();
}
```

How would I resolve this?

Comment: Please add a [MCVE] to your question. Without that there isn't much we can tell about your problem...

Comment: Show more code. What can I say when I see only a few lines. That means nothing.

Comment: Your question is not complete please give a better picture of the question

Comment: @anton86993 *"more code"* Ughh.. 9 chars for something most people won't want to see. Instead note that 1) `[mcve]` (6 chars) in a comment auto-expands to [mcve]. 2) An MCVE (by definition) includes only the problem code, plus enough to put the problem on-screen. 3) There are two *close reasons* which mention (among other things) 'no MCVE'.

Comment: By more code I ment something at least usefull.

Comment: See [*How to Use the Focus Subsystem*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html), which recommends `requestFocusInWindow()`.

Comment: @trashgod That comment seems to have a repeato in the link. But the all seeing (well, on the open interwebs in any case) Google tells me you meant.. [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) ..

Answer (score 0):

The jTextField1ActionPerformed will be called when an action is preformed on the jTextField. Have you tried calling jTextField1.requestFocus method after you call JFrame.setVisible?

Comment: See the tutorial cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326710/jtextfield-in-jdialog-box-is-not-getting-focused#comment67911822_40326710).